# Why BaseViewModel in MVC?

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in MVC and working on MVC 3. Can anybody explain what is the advantages of using a BaseViewModel in MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps you avoid duplicating code. For example, on a blog you may want to display a list of tags on each page. One way you could do it is by adding a `List<Tag>` property to each viewmodel. Or, you could create one `BaseViewModel` with a `List<Tag>` property to save cluttering your viewmodels with the same property.

From this:

```cs
class HomeViewModel
{
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

class PostsViewModel
{
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

To this:

```cs
abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        Tags = GetTagsFromSomewhere();
    }
} 

class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel { }
class PostsViewModel : BaseViewModel { }
```

Hope this helps.